# Resize Image based on resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, xamarin

`iOS` supports images with different resolution. We just need to add `@2x` and/or `@3x` and the right image for the right resolution is chosen.
But what if we display an image from the internet.

I have a `UITableView` that displays images along some text.
the original image downloaded from the internet has a size of `400x400`, on a `iPhone 4s` display it should it should be resized to `29x29`, on `iPhone 5` to `58x58` and on `iPhone 6` to `87x87`.

any best practices on how to solve this?

PS: I know how to resize the images, just need to know how to find the factor/scale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`?